# How to use extern c strings in cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to use c strings in a c library in a go program, but error occurs:

`a.h` file:

```
extern const char *s[];
```

`a.c` file:

```
const char *s[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I compile the two files to `liba.a`

`main.go` file:

```
package main

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -la
// #include"a.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
        x := 1
        fmt.Println(x)
        fmt.Println(len(C.s))
        fmt.Println(C.GoString(C.s[x]))
}
```

then I run the code with command

```
go run main.go
```

I got the error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

how to fix it? thanks

go version: `go version go1.15.7 linux/amd64`

Comment: Don't put tags in the title.

Comment: How do you build your archive file ? Why not use an object ( `.o` )

Comment: I build the archive file with command `gcc -c -o a.o a.c && ar rcs liba.a a.o`. The problem I face is to use c interface in go. If I use object files, there are too many files to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in C are not transparently handled by cgo.

There is what is known as *idiomatic* Go to map C memory to something Go can naturally manipulate. Here is a working example (`main.go`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -la
// #include "./a.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    x := 1
    fmt.Println(x)
    fmt.Println(len(C.s)) // Note, Go has no idea so it says 0.

    cStr := (*[1 << 30]*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&C.s))[x]

    fmt.Println(C.GoString(cStr))
}
```

The key piece being `(*[1 << 30]*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&C.s))`. What this says is interpret `&C.s` as a very large constant size array ("large enough for anyone"...), but extract only the element of interest `[x]` from it.

The use of `unsafe.Pointer()` should be a warning that looking beyond the end of the actual C array will yield unpredictable results. Indeed, it might crash the program.